# Update Firestore document field at high frequency

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firestore, developing an application using `NodeJS` and Firestore as the database to fetch and update the data.

Sample Firestore structure is as given below:

```
CollectionA:
    name: "name"
    id: "id"
    status: "status"
```

Let's assume, the `status` field can take one of the below string value.
start, in_progress, pending, end.

Fields `name` and `id` are updated once while created and the field `status` can be updated multiple times (in terms of milliseconds).

I would like to understand the below items:

1. Does the below update snippet makes sure the data is written to the backend and then goes to the next line of instruction. Or only the meta-data is updated and yet to be written to backend db?

```
await docRef.update({
    status: "in_progress",
});
```

2. Is there any time limit on updating a particular field in a document? Means the number of writes can be made to a particular field in 1 second?

Note: I would not be able to use the batch commit, as I am using the `status` field as a control signal to call specific blocks of code.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation for [`update`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) says, it returns:

> A Promise [that is] resolved once the data has been successfully written to the backend

Since you're using `await`, the statement will complete once the promise from the `update` call resolves.

So if you wrap it in an exception handler:

```
try {
  await docRef.update({
    status: "in_progress",
  });
  //  If you get here, the write completed on the server
}
catch (error) {
  //  If you get here, the write failed
  console.error(error);
}
```

All limits are documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas). The most relevant one seems to be this soft limit:

> Maximum sustained write rate to a document
>
> 1 per second
>
> Sustaining a write rate above once per second increases latency and causes contention errors. This is not a hard limit, and you can surpass the limit in short bursts.

As this explains, you can exceed the limit for short periods, which seems to be your use-case.

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks for the detailed explanation. 
A followup query, since I am updating a particular document field as higher rate (in terms of milliseconds), would it throw an error if any of the updates / writes failed during this short period? Or does it go under the radar?

Comment: As said in the documentation, the 1 write per document per second is a soft limit, and can be exceeded in short bursts. As said in my answer, that seems to match with your use-case. But if you exceed that limit on a single document for longer periods of time, you can see contention in those writes.

Comment: Appreciate your help. This is really helpful. 
Yea, as you mentioned in my case writes should not fail as I am writing max 4 writes but in short bursts.

Comment: I have gone through the documents. "can be exceeded in short bursts", is there a quantification for this?

Comment: No. As said, this is a soft limit; it's not something that was coded into the system, but a consequence of needing to replicate the data across multiple data centers before acknowledging the write back to the client.

Comment: Ok, understood. I am thinking to run as it is and catch errors if ```ABORTED``` is reported. And hopefully, I can add some delay and retry the same write again.